# CakePHP - calling a component 's function from a view

Tags: cakephp

How do I call a function from a component from a view? (ctp file)
Is that even a good practice to do that?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 8):

i suggest wrapping the component methods in a helper, and then using the usual route to access the helper.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan, I'll also suggest helpers after using it in my code.

Answer (score 6):

For most components you could use something like:

```
App::import('Component', 'YourComponent');
$theComponent = new YourComponent();
$theComponent->yourMethod();
```

However, components are meant to share functionality used by controllers, so usually you should avoid calling components from views.

Answer (score 5):

ALL IS POSSIBLE!

Component:

```
    function initialize(&$controller){
        $this->controller =& $controller;
        $this->controller->set('YourComponent', new YourComponent());
    }
```

View:

```
<?php $YourComponent->doAction() ... ?>
```

Comment: This is good way, I declare public $components = array("compo1"); Then I set the component: $this->set("compo1", $this->compo1); It worked!

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is it is not good practice to do that. Think of a view as something designers would work with. You want to keep your code in the models and controllers if at a possible. If it has to do with reusable view content, consider moving the controller to an element or a helper, as that is what they are intended for.

If you provide more details, we can be more specific to how to implement something if you already have a code base we can reference.

Comment: My opinion is that it is a judgement call. Code is code, logic is logic. Some of it belongs in the Controller, some in the Model, and some in the View. But **some** code needs to be accessible **anywhere**. Take **cosine** as an example. Take **today's date** as an example. What possible reason could you have to restrict those functions to only one piece of the MVC paradigm, simply because we've invented a paradigm?

Comment: It has nothing to do with MVC paradigms @UncaAlby and more about SOLID. Why should the the rendering system need to know about doing math? Rendering HTML has no reason to know about math.

Answer (score 0):

In cakephp 3

```
$config = new \Cake\Controller\ComponentRegistry();
$CustomComponent = new \App\Controller\Component\CustomComponent ($config);
```